# PHP mysql_query returning TRUE for SELECT

Tags: php, mysql

I'm experimenting with stored procedures to return me a recursive parent list.
But rather than returning me a result, like in PhpMyAdmin, `mysql_query` simply returns a boolean true.

```
mysql_query("DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `GetAncestry`") or die(mysql_error());

$sql = "[CREATE SQL FUNCTION THAT LOOPS TO RETURN A STRING CONTAINING A COMMA DELIMITED STRING OF ID's]";

mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

$sql = "SELECT SubProcessID,GetAncestry(SubProcessID) as parents from prodsubprocess where SubProcessID = {$processID}";

mysql_query($sql) //<--- Returns TRUE, but in PhpMyAdmin returns 7,6,8
```

Comment: You're saying... PhpMyAdmin returns the expected set of data, right? but the function mysql_query returns true but not data set, right? EDIT: Ok, I understand now that you updated your question, let me check

Comment: @JuanBonnett Yep, I'd expect to retrieve the data using `mysql_fetch_array`, but instead all I'm getting is a boolean.

Comment: Stop using the deprcated `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_` or `PDO` with prepared statements.

Comment: @Jens Its a large existing CRM that uses mysql_query throughout.

Comment: Agree with Jens, in case you cannot change your mysql_* thing, I suggest you try with a true value instead of {$processID}

Comment: I'd seriously consider migrating to a more secure CRM system! :D

Comment: @ChrisEvans In house custom built system.

Comment: mysql_ has more holes in it than swiss cheese, mate. :S

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [documentation:](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

> For `SELECT`, `SHOW`, `DESCRIBE`, `EXPLAIN` and other statements
>   returning `resultset`, `mysql_query()` returns a resource on success,
>   or FALSE on error.

You need to use `mysql_fetch_assoc` for the purpose as

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   //fetch result
}
```

> **Note:** `mysql_*` is depricated ; Please use `PDO`() prepared statements for the database queries

Comment: You should add the reference if you use part of text from the documentation

Comment: I don't understand why this is the accepted answer. It doesn't appear to show the solution to the question. If `mysql_query` is returning `TRUE`, how does this change that? Personally, I have to use a server that I don't have control over. I have no influence on the system administrator, and the pdo_mysql and mysqli extensions are not enabled. I have to use mysql_* functions, and this doesn't answer my question. I am already using `mysql_fetch_assoc` and in doing so, I get a warning that the parameter is a boolean value. I have confirmed that it is `TRUE` despite doing a `SELECT` statement.

Comment: It does as OP wants the result set too

Answer (score 3):

As you can see int the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php):

> For other type of SQL statements, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc,
>   mysql_query() returns TRUE on success or FALSE on error.
>
> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning
>   resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on
>   error.

You have to cal `mysql_fetch_assoc` to get the values.

**Stop using the deprcated mysql_* API. Use mysqli_ or PDO with prepared statements**

Answer (score 1):

First thing I must note is: Do not use mysql_ anymore, go to mysqli_.

You also want to use prepared statements.

On phpmyadmin it simply returns all results automatically as that's the way it's been coded. If you simply execute the query, all it's telling you is whether or not it was executed successfully, which in this case, as it is TRUE, then it is working.

What you want to do in this case is:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    print_r($row);
}
```

But seriously, check out prepared statements. There is a lot of information on that on php.net, simply look here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

The "Examples" area has plenty of basic info for you.

Answer (score 0):

In Phpmyadmin you will get result automatically for that stored procedure. But at php level, it gives you result status either TRUE or FALSE. If you want to see the results at PHP level then you must use loping construct to loop through returned DB resource to get each value.

Here is code for fetching data through loop.

```
// Code goes Here.
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
    print_r($row);
}
```